# Django Webpack Loader Apache2

Tags: reactjs, linux, apache, django-rest-framework, django-webpack-loader

I have a project with webpackloader djangorest-react js , all works fine in production but i need to launch django server everytime...
My goal is to run django and my react project with apache2 by mod_wsgi, i can run the django project but the react stay unaccessible...

Here is the working configuration of apache2 for django which work perfectly.

```
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin support@flexiwork.fr
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName www.flexiwork.fr
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        Alias /static /home/olivier/coworking/API/static
        <Directory /home/olivier/coworking/API/static>
         Require all granted
        </Directory>
        Alias /media /home/olivier/coworking/API/backend/media
        <Directory /home/olivier/coworking/API/backend/media>
         Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/olivier/coworking/API>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                  Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        #LogLevel info
        #WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/olivier/coworking/API/backend/wsgi.py process-group=coworking
        WSGIDaemonProcess coworking python-path=/home/olivier/coworking/API python-home=/home/olivier/coworking/API/env processes=5 threads=15
        WSGIProcessGroup coworking
</VirtualHost>
```

I think i need to use another deamon or a proxy but i'm a little lost if you have any links or advise thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello anyone with the same environnement please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was loading the wrong setting file in wsgi choices in django after the build, it was not an apache2 problem, here is my configuration file :

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
#from ws4redis.uwsgi_runserver import uWSGIWebsocketServer

#Here use your production settings configuration
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backend.production_settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

_django_app = get_wsgi_application()
#_websocket_app = uWSGIWebsocketServer()

def application(environ, start_response):
    if environ.get('PATH_INFO').startswith(settings.WEBSOCKET_URL):
        return _websocket_app(environ, start_response)
    return _django_app(environ, start_response)
```

And don't forget to collectstatic too

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```